# Where Opera browser stores its cookies

Tags: cookies, browser, vb6, opera

I am developing a VB tool for clean cookies.
FF and IE has specified path for store cookies and I just delete files in these path.
But I don't really know where Opera store the cookies and how to delete Opera cookies.
Please give me a advice.

Comment: In my case these are in Opera profile folder under AppData, in cookies4.dat file. How to find it and can you just delete that file, I don't know.

Comment: Is it vb.net or vb6; why both tags?

Comment: actually i code with vb6

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is pretty old. On 1 January, 2020, Opera 65.0.3467.78 uses

`%AppData%\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable`

There is a "cookies" file that is in SQLite format in that directory. There is also a "cookies-journal" file in that directory.

Information about managing cookies in Opera is available at:

https://help.opera.com/en/latest/web-preferences/#cookies

Answer (score 1):

Opera stores its cookies in `%appdata%\Opera\Opera\cookies4.dat`, and you can just delete the file.  If you want to delete individual cookies, that would take a lot more work.

Comment: The file format is [documented](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/#cookies), at least, if you want to delete individual cookies. Also note that deleting the file while the browser is running will have no effect.

Comment: I just installed the latest version and I think they are stored in `%appdata%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Cookies`. Maybe they changed it in some release. If this is true, I'd suggest you edit the answer to keep it up to date.